# "grep THIS foo.txt > THIS.txt" gives an error in Makefile, not in bash, when grep output is empty

Tags: makefile, grep

Makefile is as follows :

```
THIS.txt : foo.txt  
        grep THIS foo.txt > $@
```

When grep output is empty (no THIS in foo.txt), make gives an error message, bash does not :

```
$ make  
make:*** [THIS.txt] Error 1

$ grep THIS foo.txt > THIS.txt  

$ grep THIS foo.txt 2>&1
```

How come? How should I modify my makefile to avoid an error message when `grep` output is empty?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`grep` doesn't give an error in bash, but it *does* return a non-zero exit code:

```
> grep THIS foo.txt 2>&1
> echo $?
1
```

If you want to get rid of that non-zero exit code, so that `make` won't flag it as an error, you can do this:

```
THIS.txt : foo.txt
     grep THIS foo.txt > $@ || true
```

The `|| true` bit says "if there is a nonzero exit code, return the exit code of `true` instead (which is always `0` in bash).

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a simple way to distinguish a non-zero exit code due to an empty output from a non-zero exit code due to anything else ? So as no to force to true systematically.

Comment: Empty output doesn't automatically mean non-zero exit code. It's just specific to how `grep` operates - if it doesn't find any matches, it exits with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @user584744: you should accept this answer, it's fundamental to how Unix executables work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in tagging as accepted ! Only not familiar with the process yet. Thanks for the answer, it is perfect for my problem, and I modified my makefile accordingly...

Comment: +1 I needed this in a cron-ed script which uses `bash -e` Apparently the script will silently fail when I run with `bash -e` and grep does not find anything.

Comment: It's not really correct to say that `grep` doesn't "give an error" in Bash. The behavior is identical, but Bash ignores the error exit code (unless you have `set -e`). There is no explicit human-readable error message when there are no matches, but there is still an error; and this is well-defined and useful behavior. Every well-behaved command operates this way.